# What's the main difference between $S^{-1}A$ and ${\rm Frac}(A)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring. I completely know what $S^{-1}A$ is, but I am still confused about ${\rm Frac}(A)$.

What's the main difference between $S^{-1}A$ and ${\rm Frac}(A)$?

What I know is that there's no multiplicative set $S$ in ${\rm Frac}(A)$, so for ${\rm Frac}(A)$, if $a/b=c/d$, then it just means that $ar/br=c/d$, for some $r$ in ring $A$, right?

Comment: are you assuming $A$ is an integral domain? as far as I know the notation $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ does not have a common meaning if $A$ is not an integral domain. if $A$ is not  necessarily an integral domain, what do you mean by $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$? (maybe the "total ring of fractions"?)

Comment: "What I knew is that there's no multiplicative set S in Frac(A)". The subset of units is always a multiplicative set in any commutative ring so this idea is not true.

Comment: The total ring of fractions $Q(A)$ is $S^{-1}A$ with $S$ the set of non-zero divisors. The main theorem is that the natural map $A\to Q(A)$ is injective. So will be the natural maps $A\to S^{-1} A\to Q(A)$ whenever $S$ doesn't contain any zero divisor. $S^{-1}A = Q(A)$ iff $S$ is the whole set of non-zero divisors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you meant for $A$ to be an integral domain. In that case Frac($A$) is just a version of $S^{-1}A$, where $S = A \backslash \{0\}$.

$S^{-1}A$ allows you to "divide" the elements of $A$ by the elements of $S$.

You can visualize the difference using $A = \mathbb{Z}$. $S:=\{2^n \vert n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a multiplicatively closed subset and $S^{-1}A$ will be the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ divided by powers of 2. If you want to make sure that that is really what we defined here you can verify: $S^{-1}A \ni \dfrac{z}{2^n} = \dfrac{z'}{2^m} \iff \exists r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ 2^{r+m}z = 2^{r+n}z' \in \mathbb{Z} $(this condition is the definition of the equivalence relation that we quotient $A \times S$ by to get $S^{-1}A$) $\iff$ (WLOG we assume $n \geq m$) $z = 2^{n-m}z' \in \mathbb{Z} \iff \dfrac{z}{2^n} = \dfrac{z'}{2^m} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

This is a neat example to illustrate the difference.

However, Frac$(A) = \mathbb{Q}$.